# jqGrid sort on first load

Tags: jquery, xml, sorting, jqgrid

I have the following code for my grid (I use an XML file in the same directory as data source).

```
var handsetGrid = $("#products").jqGrid({
    url: 'catalog.xml',
    datatype: "xml",
    colNames:["SKU", "Name", "Brand", "Description", "Metadescription"],
    colModel:[
        {name:"sku",  key: true, index:"sku", width:100, xmlmap:"sku", align:"right", sortable:true},
        {name:"Name", index:"Name", width:300, sortable:true, xmlmap:">name>en"},
        {name:"Brand", index:"Brand", width:100, sortable:true, xmlmap:"brand"},
        {name:"description", index:"description", width:400, classes:"desc1", xmlmap:"description1>en", formatter:descFormatter},
        {name:"metadescriptionEn", index:"metadescriptionEn", width:400, classes:"desc1", xmlmap:"metadescription>en", formatter:descFormatter}
    ],
    width: 1300,
    height:480,
    shrinkToFit:false,
    rownumbers: true,
    scroll: true,
    rowNum:22,
    ignoreCase: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    sortname: "Name",
    sortorder: "asc",
    sortable: true,
    loadonce: true,
    pager: "#pager",
    caption: "Handsets",                    
    xmlReader: {
        root: "products",
        row: "product",
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "sku"               
    },
    loadComplete: function(data) {
        // test whether we have initial loadind and the "data" has XML type
        if (data.nodeType) {
            myXMLdata = data; // save original XML data                         
        }
    },
    subGrid: true,
    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
        var subgrid_table_id;
        subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";
        jQuery("#" + subgrid_id).html("<table id='" + subgrid_table_id + "' class='scroll'></table>");
        jQuery("#" + subgrid_table_id).jqGrid( {
            datatype:'xmlstring',
            datastr: myXMLdata,
            colNames: [ 'Id', 'Name', 'Duration', 'Price'],
            colModel: [
                {name:"ppid",index:"ppid",width:80, xmlmap:">id"},
                {name:"ppname",index:"ppname",width:150, xmlmap:">name>en"},
                {name:"ppduration",index:"ppduration",width:85, xmlmap:">priceperduration>duration>en", formatter: durationFormatter},
                {name:"ppprice",index:"ppprice",width:80, xmlmap:">priceperduration>price", formatter: priceFormatter}
            ],
            gridview: true,
            xmlReader: {
                root: "products>product:has('sku:contains('"+row_id+"')')>priceplansavailable",
                row: "priceplan",
                repeatitems: false
            }                           
        });
    }       

}); 

$("#handsets").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:false});
$("#handsets").jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#pager",{caption:"Search Bar", title:"Toggle Search Toolbar", buttonicon :'ui-icon-pin-s',
    onClickButton:function(){
        handsetGrid[0].toggleToolbar();
    }
});

$("#handsets").jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#pager",{caption:"Clear", title:"Clear Search", buttonicon :'ui-icon-refresh',
    onClickButton:function(){
        handsetGrid[0].clearToolbar();
    }
});

$("#handsets").jqGrid('filterToolbar', {defaultSearch:'cn'});
```

My problem is when I load the grid I want it to be already sorted for the column : Name. 
I expected to be working with these three parameters :

- sortname: "Name",
- sortorder: "asc",
- sortable: true,

After clicking on the columns it is working properly, just the first sort is not working (after loading the page).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use remote datatype like "xml" or "json", **the server** is responsible to provide the **sorted** data.

If you cannot do this, you can trigger the `reloadGrid` inside of `loadComplete`, but you should use `setTimeout` JavaScript method to allow the complete the first loading process.

To have no recursions you should place `"reloadGrid"` inside of `if (data.nodeType)` block of `loadComplete`.

**UPDATED:** [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) have the option `forceClientSorting: true`, which solves the problem. The option allows to force sorting and filtering of data (if optional `postData.filters` is set) *before* the first page will be displayed.

Comment: It works fine like this: if( data.nodeType ){
 myXMLdata = data; 
 setTimeout( function() { $("#products").jqGrid('setGridParam',{ page: 1 }).trigger("reloadGrid"); }, 1 );
} ... 1 milliseconds is enough to make it works. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Presumably the `setTimeout` is only required because the data is coming from a file?

Comment: i am getting to recursion with if (data.nodeType)

Comment: @kozla13: I don't understand how you can have recursion. **Do you use `datatype: "xml", loadonce: true` like in the question?** `data.nodeType` will be changed only with XML data. You can test for `datatype` alternatively: see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8119695/315935).

Comment: @Oleg: i am using json data, that was the problem. Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: What will be the solution if we are getting `json` type data? I am reloading the grid in `loadComplete` without `data.nodeType` condition.. and i am getting continuous recursion

Comment: @sohaiby: The callback `loadComplete` will be called **on every loading/reloading of the grid**. So it's very bad idea to reload the grid in `loadComplete`. You will have continuous recursion of cause. So one should reload the grid only at the first load and trigger `reloadGrid` only inside of  `setTimeout` to allow jqGrid process the previous loading till the end.

Comment: @Oleg What should be the value of `sortname` if I do not want to sort by column name? I only want to sort by `groupHeader`.

Comment: You should not include and `sortname` at all, then it will be used default `sortname: ""`, which means no sorting.

Answer (score 0):

try running

```
handsetgrid.sortGrid("Name");
```

after loadComplete

Comment: How can you now loadComplete has finished (there is not an event like afterLoad), because I tried to put this at the end but no effect at all except my table gets empty.

Comment: you have that parameter there in loadComplete: function(data) {