# Default sorting of jqgrid on particular field when grid loads

Tags: jqgrid

I want to load a grid with default sorting on it's one of field. I done this by adding sortname and sortorder to my grid,but when grid is loaded sorting sign is shown on a header of that field.But records are sorted when i click on pagination next button not on grid load.

Is anyone know why it is not sorting on grid load?

@UPDATE:
hi kees, I am using my datatype as XML and my config. is as follows:

```js
jQuery("#userList").jqGrid({
    url: '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/userJqGrid?q=1&action=fetchData&userCookie=<%= encodedCookie%>',
    datatype: 'xml',
    mtype: 'GET',
    colNames:['<%= userProp.getProperty(userColNames[0])%>',
              '<%= userProp.getProperty(userColNames[1])%>',
              '<%= userProp.getProperty(userColNames[2])%>',
              '<%= userProp.getProperty(userColNames[3])%>',
              '<%= userProp.getProperty(userColNames[4])%>',
              '<%= userProp.getProperty(userColNames[5])%>'
    ],
    colModel:[
        {name:'<%= userColNames[0]%>',index:'<%= userColNames[0]%>',
            width:120,sortable:true,editable:true,editrules:{required:true},formoptions:{rowpos:1, elmprefix:'*'}},
        {name:'<%= userColNames[1]%>',index:'<%= userColNames[1]%>',
            width:130,sortable:true,editable:true},
        {name:'<%= userColNames[2]%>',index:'<%= userColNames[2]%>',
            width:100,sortable:true,editable:true,editrules:{required:true},formoptions:{rowpos:3, elmprefix:'*'}},
        {name:'<%= userColNames[3]%>',index:'<%= userColNames[3]%>',
            width:180,sortable:true,editable:true,editrules:{email:true,required:true},formoptions:{rowpos:4, elmprefix:'*'}},
        {name:'<%= userColNames[4]%>',index:'<%= userColNames[4]%>',
            width:100,sortable:true,editable:true},
        {name:'<%= userColNames[5]%>',index:'<%= userColNames[5]%>',
            width:100,sortable:true,editable:true},
    ],
    pager:'#pager1',
    rowNum:'<%=appProp.getProperty("per_page_records")%>',
    height:'auto',
    viewrecords:true,
    loadonce:true,
    sortable:true,
    width:'100%',
    gridview: true,
    autowidth:true,
    shrinkToFit:false,
    ignoreCase:true,
    editurl:'<%=request.getContextPath()%>/userJqGrid?q=1&action=addData&userCookie=<%=encodedCookie%>',
    caption: 'User Records',
    sortname:'<%=userColNames[14]%>',
    sortorder:'asc',
    onSelectRow: function (id){
        checkAndSetCookie();
    },
    onSortCol : function(){
        checkAndSetCookie();
    },
    onPaging : function(){
        checkAndSetCookie();
    },
    onSearch : function(){
        checkAndSetCookie();
    },
    loadComplete: function(){
        checkAndSetCookie();
    }
});
```

Comment: Which data backend do you use? So how your data is loaded? JSON, Local array, etc? And could you post your jqGrid configuration here please so we cam help you.

Comment: hi kees, I have added and update for mine config.

Comment: And if you check with FireBug (console) is there a sidx and sord parameter in the URL?

Comment: yes there is idx=company_id&sord=asc present in URL  and sorting is done when i click on pagination next button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use remote `datatype` (`datatype: 'xml'` or `datatype: 'json'`) **the server** is responsible for sorting of the data at the first load. If you use `loadonce: true` and want to sort the data *only on the client side* you have to reload jqGrid directly after the first loading. The corresponding code could be about the following

```js
loadComplete: function (data) {
    var $this = $(this),
        datatype = $this.getGridParam('datatype');

    if (datatype === "xml" || datatype === "json") {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.trigger("reloadGrid");
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork has the option `forceClientSorting: true`, which can be used in combination with `loadonce: true` option. The option `forceClientSorting: true` force client side sorting and filtering. It makes the code described in the answer unneeded.