# Set start page of jqgrid when loadonce: true

Tags: jqgrid

Is it possible to set another page than page one as start page when I'm using loadonce: true in jqgrid?

Right now I perform a reloadgrid after the first load, and I dont think thats really good performance wice..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have to call `reloadGrid` somewhere inside of `loadComplete`. You should do this only once at the loading from the server (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8119695/315935), but use `[{page: thePageNumber}]` as the second parameter of `reloadGrid`).

The only optimization which I would recommend you is the usage of very low value of `rowNum` (for example 1) at the initialization. Before call of `reloadGrid` you can increase the `rowNum` to the value which you really want to see the user (25 for example). To reduce the `flicker` you can *hide* the `<table>` inside of hidden `<div>` and show it inside of `loadComplete` in case of `$(this).getGridParam('datatype') === 'local'`. I didn't tested what I describe, but I hope that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the api to set the start page:

```
$('#yourgrid').jqGrid('setGridParam', {page: '10'});
```

Comment: Can you do this before the initial xHr request to the action?   What event do you subscribe to when doing this?   This is where I am stuck