# Why does jqgrid sorting is not wokring?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

This is my code, I am trying to populated the grid using the data added in data.json, a default sorting is supposed to be added to the jqgrid which doesn't happen. I have given data in data.json which will be populated on the grid. Paging works but sorting doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/jqgrid/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jqgrid/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jqgrid/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqgrid/4.6.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jqgrid/jqgridscreen-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jqgrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/jqgrid/jquery.jqGrid.src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jqgrid/ui.jqgrid.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jqgrid/ui.multiselect.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/jqgrid/custom.css" />

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>jqGrid Loading Data - JSON</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <table id="jqGrid"></table>
        <div id="jqGridPager"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript"> 

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                    url: 'data.json',
                    datatype: "json",
                    colModel: [
                        { label: 'Category Name', name: 'CategoryName', width: 75, sorttype:'string' },
                        { label: 'Product Name', name: 'ProductName', width: 90, sorttype:'string' },
                        { label: 'Country', name: 'Country', width: 100, sorttype:'string'},
                        { label: 'Price', name: 'Price', width: 80, sorttype:'float' },
                        { label: 'Quantity', name: 'Quantity', width: 80, sorttype:'integer' }                   
                    ],
                    loadonce: true,
                    gridview: true,
                    autoencode: true,
                    width: 780,
                    height: 200,
                    rowNum: 15,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    pager: "#jqGridPager",
                    loadComplete: function () {
                        var $self = $(this);
                        if ($self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") === "json") {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $self.trigger("reloadGrid"); // Call to fix client-side sorting
                            }, 50);
                        }
                    }

                });
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is the mistake and why sorting doesn't occur?

Comment: Which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) oder an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? In any way you should include only required JS and CSS files and never include duplicates (for example one should use either `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` or `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`).

Comment: By the way, if you use **free jqGrid** fork, then you can remove your current `loadComplete` and to add `forceClientSorting: true` option instead. The option works only in combination with `loadonce: true`. It allows to sort and to filter the data locally direct after loading from the server. See **UPDATE** part of [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8119695/315935)

Answer (score 0):

If you use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork, then you can remove your current `loadComplete` and to add `forceClientSorting: true` option instead. The option works only in combination with `loadonce: true`. It allows to sort and to filter the data locally direct after loading from the server. See **UPDATE** part of [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8119695/315935)