# Sort in a Jqgrid (on Load Complete)

Tags: sorting, jqgrid

I'm facing the same problem as explain in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619395/jqgrid-sort-on-first-load).

In my case, I'm loading the data into the grid with JSON. Unfortunately I cannot change the query to do the sorting so I've tried to replicate what Oleg and Ruffp suggest but i don't use "if (data.nodeType)". Now even if the grid is sorting, I can't select any row because when I place the mouse pointer inside the grid, it starts to blink or flash (Maybe I'm having recursions in the execution of the grid, but I'm not sure).

Should I put the timeout inside an if clause? Using something different than data.nodeType because I'm using JSON? In that case, which should be the clause?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct you will find the answer on your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10287338/315935). I suppose that you use `datatype: "json"` and `loadonce: true` options and loads from the server full *unsorted* data (without paging and sorting). If you implemented paging on the server, but no sorting then you should find the solution of your problem in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9047197/315935).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works like a charm ! And actually you were right. I'm using `datatype: "json"` and `loadonce: true"`. And the best of the solution is that the blinks and flashes stopped. So now I'm able to pick any of the rows of the grid. Thanks again :)